# I am trying to integrate the MLflow UI with an existing Django application that utilizes JWT authentication for user management

Tags: python, jwt, django-authentication, bearer-token, mlflow

The goal is to ensure that access to the MLflow UI is authenticated using JWT tokens from our Django application.

Current Setup
Existing Django application with JWT authentication implemented.
MLflow UI running separately.
I have Django application with user authentication and authorization functionalities.
RESTful endpoint to validate JWT tokens, ensuring expiry and permissions.
My aim is to integrate the JWT token validation process with the MLflow server. Here's the intended workflow:
Send the JWT token in the headers of requests made to the MLflow server.
Validate the token against the Django RESTful endpoint.

Desired Integration
I aim to integrate JWT authentication from our Django application into the MLflow UI. Here's how I envision the process:

Configure the MLflow UI to accept JWT tokens for authentication.
Users attempting to access the MLflow UI must provide a valid JWT token.
Upon receiving a token, MLflow UI should validate it against our Django application's JWT authentication mechanism.
If the token is valid and the user is authenticated, grant access to the MLflow UI.
If the token is invalid or the user fails authentication, deny access to the MLflow UI.

Additional Information
I have reviewed the documentation for both MLflow and Django regarding authentication but require assistance in bridging the gap between them.
Any guidance or best practices for securely integrating JWT authentication with the MLflow UI would be greatly appreciated.
I aim to ensure a seamless user experience while maintaining robust security measures.

Current Challenges
I have encountered difficulties in configuring MLflow UI to accept JWT tokens and authenticate users against our Django application.
Lack of clear documentation or examples for integrating JWT authentication with MLflow UI is hindering progress.